# How to stop printing comma and space after last digit in c

Tags: c, while-loop

Here is the program I wrote:

```
int main(void)
{
    int d1, d2;

    d1 = 48;
    while (d1 < 58)
    {
        d2 = d1 + 1;
        while (d2 < 58)
        {
            putchar(d1);
            putchar(d2);
            putchar(',');
            putchar(' ');
            d2++;
        }
        d1++;
    }

    putchar(10);
    return (0);
}
```

Output of the program is as follows:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 78, 79, 89, $
```

I want the output like this:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 78, 79, 89$
```

How can I get the comma to stop before last digit?

Comment: Change the logic to printing a comma and a space *before* printing the number. But only if you have already printed a number before. So you need to keep track of that state and put an `if` conditional in there.

Comment: `44` and `32` could be represented more understandably by `','` and `' '`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve your problem. You can print a separator before each of the outputs except the first one.

Note also that it would be much more readable to use `'0'` and `'9'` instead of hard coding ASCII values such as `48`...

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int d1, d2, n = 0;

    for (d1 = '0'; d1 <= '9'; d1++) {
        for (d2 = d1 + 1; d2 <= '9'; d2++, n++) {
            if (n > 0) {
                putchar(',');
                putchar(' ');
            }
            putchar(d1);
            putchar(d2);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an alternative using a separator string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int d1, d2;
    const char *sep = "";

    for (d1 = '0'; d1 <= '9'; d1++) {
        for (d2 = d1 + 1; d2 <= '9'; d2++) {
            fputs(sep, stdout);
            sep = ", ";
            putchar(d1);
            putchar(d2);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way of doing what *@chqrlie* does i.e. to print separator before each character.
Before the first character the separators are null characters and for subsequent characters the separators are `','` and `' '`.

Implementation:

```
int main(void)
{
    int d1, d2;
    int sep1 = 0;
    int sep2 = 0;

    d1 = 48;
    while (d1 < 58)
    {
        d2 = d1 + 1;
        while (d2 < 58)
        {
            putchar(sep1);
            putchar(sep2);
            putchar(d1);
            putchar(d2);
            d2++;
            sep1 = ',';
            sep2 = ' ';
        }
        d1++;
    }

    putchar(10);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I like your approach specially because it's one less block of code.

Comment: @JardelLucca: the code outputs 2 null bytes, which may not appear on your screen, but will be present in an output file. This approach works better with a string `sep` initialized as `""`, output with `fputs(sep, stdout)` and updated as `sep = ", "` after the first number.